# Jasig CAS login workflow

Tags: spring-security, cas

I have an issue with CAS (v. 3.5.2) login page.

I enabled allowServicesRedirect property (cas-servlet.xml), so when I logged out, the servers redirects to cas login page.

However, clicking in submit button the login page is refreshed. In a second click, login happens normaly.

I worked hard in this issue in last days, but I did not get a solution.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My .jsp page tries to load a nonexistent file, however the server (jetty) returns a 302 code (instead 404). Adding the file, this issue is solved.